# JPA Stored Procedure result set mappings and NonUniqueResultException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm fairly new to JPA and am trying to use a stored procedure to run a query and map its results to my java classes.

Here are the tables

```
    CREATE TABLE dbo.Branding 
(
    Branding_ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_Branding PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    BrandingType_ID INT,
    Reseller_ID INT NULL,
    Host VARCHAR(MAX) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.BrandingResource 
(
    BrandingResource_ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_BrandingResource PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    Branding_ID INT NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    [Value] VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL 
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.BrandingType 
(
    BrandingType_ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_BrandingType PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    Description VARCHAR(255)
)
```

Here are the entities:

```
@Table(name = "[Branding]")
@Entity
public class Branding extends CommonDomainBase
{
@Id
@Column(name = "branding_id")
private int id;

@OneToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "brandingtype_id", nullable = false)
private BrandingType type;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "branding_id", referencedColumnName = "branding_id")
private Set<BrandingResource> brandingResources;

@Column(name = "reseller_id", nullable = true)
private Integer resellerId;

@Column(name = "host", nullable = true)
private String host;


}


@Table(name = "[BrandingResource]")
@Entity
public class BrandingResource extends CommonDomainBase
{
@Id
@Column(name = "BrandingResource_Id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "Name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "Value")
private String value;

}

@Table(name = "[BrandingType]")
@Entity
public class BrandingType extends CommonDomainBase
{
@Id
@Column(name = "brandingtype_id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;
}
```

I already know that the annotations on the entities are working correctly. When I use Spring Data JPA repositories to query the 3 tables to find one or find all of Branding, I get a generated query which retrieves all 3 tables in a single query.

I am now trying to extends this to allow me to do the same sort of result set mapping using a named stored procedure which I've configured in the following way:

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "Branding.getBrandingByHost", procedureName = "spGetBrandingByHost", parameters =
{ @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "host", type = String.class) }, resultSetMappings =
{ "BrandingResults" })
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "BrandingResults", entities =
{ @EntityResult(entityClass = Branding.class) })
```

The stored procedure is returning duplicate rows for each row in the branding table, due to the one to many relationship to BrandingResource.

The result set mapping when using the Spring Data JPA repository and it's generated query has duplicate rows in the same way as my procedure, and is able to handle this perfectly when mapping to the objects. When using the named stored procedure however I get the following exception:

```
javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: Call to stored procedure [spGetBrandingByHost] returned multiple results
```

I understand that I will probably need to include more result set mappings for this to work, but cannot find a example which demonstrates anything similar. Is what I'm after even possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this help? [multiple one-to-many relations ResultSetExtractor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295600/multiple-one-to-many-relations-resultsetextractor)?

Comment: @Nicholas that's the way I would have done it in the past, but I'm trying to do this with JPA annotations

Comment: Yea, I don't know, but it seems kind of complicated for annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to my own question, no you can't. Which does make sense. When automatically generating queries, hibernate what column names to expect in the result set, including any that are duplicated from a one to many/many to one relationship. A stored procedure can return any column that hibernate does not know to expect, so setting them explicitly is required.

After much digging I did find the class `org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.ResultsetMappingSecondPass` which is called to map JPA annotations to native hibernate a `org.hibernate.engine.ResultSetMappingDefinition` and, reading the source code, I can see it completely ignores most of the annotations for columns, and joining.

It would be great if `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery` could support one to many/many to one joins. For now I've created my own solution:

```
public class EntityResultSetSecondPass implements QuerySecondPass
{
    private static final String ALIAS = EntityResultSetSecondPass.class.getName() + "_alias";
    private final InFlightMetadataCollector metadataCollector;

    private int entityAliasIndex;
    private final Map<Class<?>, String> aliasMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public EntityResultSetSecondPass(final InFlightMetadataCollector metadataCollector)
    {
        this.metadataCollector = metadataCollector;
    }

    @Override
    public void doSecondPass(final Map persistentClasses) throws MappingException
    {
        for (final Object key : persistentClasses.keySet())
        {
            final String className = key.toString();
            try
            {
                final Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
                final EntityResultSet entityResultSet = clazz.getDeclaredAnnotation(EntityResultSet.class);

                if (entityResultSet == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    createEntityResultDefinition(entityResultSet, clazz);
                }
            }
            catch (final ClassNotFoundException e)
            {
                throw new HibernateException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    private void createEntityResultDefinition(final EntityResultSet entityResultSet, final Class<?> entityClass)
            throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        final List<NativeSQLQueryReturn> mappedReturns = new ArrayList<>();
        final ResultSetMappingDefinition definition = new ResultSetMappingDefinition(entityResultSet.name());
        final Map<Class<?>, FieldResult[]> returnedEntities = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

        returnedEntities.put(entityClass, entityResultSet.fields());

        for (final EntityResult entityResult : entityResultSet.relatedEntities())
        {
            returnedEntities.put(entityResult.entityClass(), entityResultSet.fields());
        }

        definition.addQueryReturn(new NativeSQLQueryRootReturn(getOrCreateAlias(entityClass), entityClass.getName(),
                getPropertyResults(entityClass, entityResultSet.fields(), returnedEntities, mappedReturns, ""),
                LockMode.READ));

        for (final EntityResult entityResult : entityResultSet.relatedEntities())
        {
            definition
                    .addQueryReturn(
                            new NativeSQLQueryRootReturn(getOrCreateAlias(entityResult.entityClass()),
                                    entityResult.entityClass().getName(), getPropertyResults(entityResult.entityClass(),
                                            entityResult.fields(), returnedEntities, mappedReturns, ""),
                                    LockMode.READ));
        }

        for (final NativeSQLQueryReturn mappedReturn : mappedReturns)
        {
            definition.addQueryReturn(mappedReturn);
        }

        metadataCollector.addResultSetMapping(definition);
    }

    private Map<String, String[]> getPropertyResults(final Class<?> entityClass, final FieldResult[] fields,
            final Map<Class<?>, FieldResult[]> returnedEntities, final List<NativeSQLQueryReturn> mappedReturns,
            final String prefix) throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        final Map<String, String[]> properties = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        for (final Field field : entityClass.getDeclaredFields())
        {
            final Column column = field.getAnnotation(Column.class);
            if (column != null)
            {
                properties.put(prefix + field.getName(), new String[]
                { column.name() });
            }
            final JoinColumn joinColumn = field.getAnnotation(JoinColumn.class);
            if (joinColumn != null)
            {
                properties.putAll(handleJoinColumn(entityClass, field, joinColumn, returnedEntities, mappedReturns));
            }
        }

        if (entityClass.getSuperclass() != null)
        {
            properties.putAll(
                    getPropertyResults(entityClass.getSuperclass(), fields, returnedEntities, mappedReturns, prefix));
        }

        return properties;
    }

    private Map<String, String[]> handleJoinColumn(final Class<?> sourceEntity, final Field field,
            final JoinColumn joinColumn, final Map<Class<?>, FieldResult[]> returnedEntities,
            final List<NativeSQLQueryReturn> mappedReturns) throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        final Map<String, String[]> properties = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        final OneToOne oneToOne = field.getAnnotation(OneToOne.class);
        if (oneToOne != null)
        {
            properties.put(field.getName(), new String[]
            { joinColumn.name() });
        }
        final OneToMany oneToMany = field.getAnnotation(OneToMany.class);

        if (oneToMany != null)
        {
            Class<?> fieldType;
            if (field.getType().isArray())
            {
                fieldType = field.getType();
            }
            else if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType()))
            {
                fieldType = Class.forName(
                        ParameterizedType.class.cast(field.getGenericType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0].getTypeName());
            }
            else
            {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("One to many only supports collection and array types");
            }

            if (returnedEntities.keySet().contains(fieldType))
            {
                properties.put(field.getName(), new String[]
                { joinColumn.name() });

                final Map<String, String[]> resolvedProperties = getPropertyResults(fieldType,
                        returnedEntities.get(fieldType), returnedEntities, mappedReturns, "element.");
                resolvedProperties.put("key", new String[]
                { joinColumn.referencedColumnName() });

                resolvedProperties.put("element", new String[]
                { joinColumn.name() });

                mappedReturns.add(new NativeSQLQueryCollectionReturn(getOrCreateAlias(fieldType),
                        sourceEntity.getName(), field.getName(), resolvedProperties, LockMode.READ));
                mappedReturns
                        .add(new NativeSQLQueryJoinReturn(getOrCreateAlias(fieldType),
                                getOrCreateAlias(sourceEntity), field.getName(), getPropertyResults(fieldType,
                                        returnedEntities.get(fieldType), returnedEntities, mappedReturns, ""),
                                LockMode.READ));
            }
        }

        return properties;
    }

    private String getOrCreateAlias(final Class<?> entityClass)
    {
        if (!aliasMap.containsKey(entityClass))
        {
            aliasMap.put(entityClass, ALIAS + entityAliasIndex++);
        }
        return aliasMap.get(entityClass);
    }
}
```

and the accompanying annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface EntityResultSet
{
    /**
     * The name of the result set
     * 
     * @return
     */
    String name();

    /**
     * The {@link FieldResult} to override those of the {@link Column}s on the
     * current {@link Entity}
     * 
     * @return
     */
    FieldResult[] fields() default {};

    /**
     * The {@link EntityResult} that define related {@link Entity}s that are
     * included in this result set.
     * 
     * </p>Note: discriminatorColumn has no impact in this usage
     * 
     * @return
     */
    EntityResult[] relatedEntities() default {};
}
```

This is all registered with hibernate via a `MetadataContributor`

The code is a bit of a mess, but it is actually working. It basically looks for `@EntityResultSet` in which the entities for a particular result set are defined. The `EntityResultSetSecondPass` looks at these given entities and generates a `ResultSetMappingDefinition` which includes all the joining meta data for collection mapping. It runs from all the standard column annotations but can be overridden with `FieldResult` defined in `@EntityResultSet`

It seems a bit nasty, but it's working nicely.