# How to write sqlite query to avoid loop in python for one-to-many database model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I have two object called RECEIPT and PARTICULAR.

Attributes of  RECEIPT object are:

- receiptNo
- particularList

Attributes of  PARTICULAR object are:

- particularId
- particularName

Also I have their respective tables. **receiptNo** is the primary key of RECEIPT table and it is the foreign key in PARTICULAR table. So for a receipt there are multiple particulars.

I want to fetch data to populate  RECEIPT object. To achieve this I can first run select query to RECEIPT table and by iterating the result using a for loop I can run another query to fetch the PARTICULAR table. Here I am calling the DB twice.

To avoid calling DB twice I tried joins also as:

```
SELECT * FROM RECEIPT r,PARTICULAR p WHERE r.RECEIPT_NO = p.RECEIPT_NO
```

However as it returns repetitive data for the RECEIPT, i.e. for each PARTICULAR row corresponding RECEIPT data are also fectching. This RECEIPT data are repetitive as multiple particularId shares same receiptNo. Due to thisI am unable to load the data properly to the RECEIPT object (Or may be I dont know how to load such resulset to the respective objects)

My actual requirement is to load RECEIPT object by forming PARTICULAR list for each receipt.

Is using the for loop and calling DB twice the only way to achieve it? 
Suggest me an efficient way to achieve this

Comment: What does "fetch data from both the tables and assign to the RECEIPT object"? You need to explain exactly what output you want, and exactly why what you tried didn't work; how did what you get differ from what you wanted?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have updated the question. My requirement is just to populate Receipt object by fetching data fron DB. But i want to know the efficient approach

Comment: Why are you attempting to append data from a related table (i.e., child info into parent)? This duplicates unnecessary data. One of the emphasis of the relational model (that underlies relational databases like SQLite) is to avoid the redundancy of data storage.

Comment: @Parfait Could you please share your approach? For me the child object list is one of the field of the parent object. If you have better database model then please share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think querying the data from the database with the JOIN approach is the most efficient way to do it.

If you make sure to ORDER BY "RECEIPT_NO" you just have to loop through the list once in python, only creating a new Receipt object every time you reach a new "RECEIPT_NO".

So the SQL becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM RECEIPT r,PARTICULAR p WHERE r.RECEIPT_NO = p.RECEIPT_NO ORDER BY RECEIPT_NO
```

And the python code could look like

```
data = query("SELECT * FROM RECEIPT r,PARTICULAR p WHERE r.RECEIPT_NO = p.RECEIPT_NO ORDER BY RECEIPT_NO")

last_receipt_nr = ""
for row in data:
    if last_receipt_nr == row.RECEIPT_NO:
        # Replace with code initializing a new Receipt object
        last_receipt_nr = row.RECEIPT_NO
    #Replace with code initializing a new Particular object
```

Comment: Thanks @jpeg. Seems this is a common situation for one-to-many relation database model. Also I have found similar question in Java world https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295600/multiple-one-to-many-relations-resultsetextractor. Here they are using Map to handle repetitive data in java side. In our case we can use Dictionary to hold your last_receipt_nr. Anyway your answer is clean and simple.